# list of 524 matrices each one with 2 colons and variable row length

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I am trying to make a list of 524 matrices each one with 2 colons and variable row length

I tried the code below:

```
> twna=list()
> for(j in 1:Insh){
+   t=matrix(ncol=2,nrow=Inevh-nan[j])
+   for(i in 1:Inevh){
+     if((is.na(rain[i,j])==F)){
+       t[i,1]=i
+       t[i,2]=rain[i,j]
+      
+     }   
+   } 
+   twna[j]=t
+ }
```

and R return this error code:

Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, 1, value = 7337L) : subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you replace

```
for(i in 1:Inevh){
```

with

```
for(i in 1:nrow(t)){
```

because you're defining the matrix as possibly having fewer rows than `Inevh` (or you could adjust the dimensions of t (awful name for a matrix variable by the way, as to take the transpose you'd be left with `t(t)`) so as not to subtract `nan[j]`.

There's probably a more idiomatic way to do it in R without the inner loop:

```
t[,1] <- 1:Inevh
t[,2] <- rain[,j]
t[is.na(rain[,j]),] <- NA
```

Comment: exactly, here my goal is to build a new list of matrices that don't contain Na's. the problem is that the number of Na's for each colon is not the same so i created a vector (nan) that contain the number of na's for each colomn then I used it for the t row number.

in the second loop i used a if function that allow me to ignore Na values so i think that the nrow and the number of entries in the inner loop+if function match perfectly.

perhaps I thnk that the list of matrices wnat is causing the problem here

Comment: Ah, bit clearer now.  How about simply `t[,1] <- which(!is.na(rain[,j]))` to record the indices of the non missing values of _rain_ and `t[,2] <- rain[!is.na(rain[,j]),j]` to store the non-missing values.  Or something along the lines to `filtererdOfNA <- apply(rain, 2, na.omit)` to automatically generate a list from the columns of _rain_ with the na's omitted

Comment: et yap ça fonctionne bien merci

Answer (score 0):

In your outer loop, you create a matrix t with `Inevh-nan[j]` rows:

```
t=matrix(ncol=2,nrow=Inevh-nan[j])
```

In your inner loop, you cycle through rows `1:Ineveh`:

```
for(i in 1:Inevh){...}
```

So unless `nan[j]==0` for all `j`, you will eventually get a subscript out of bounds error.

Comment: nan is a vctor containing the number of missing values for each j.